# Lista ligada simple (BorrarNodo) C

Tags: c, lista, punteros, nodos

Es una lista ligada en C, debe realizar 3 acciones, agregar, mostrar lista y eliminar nodo. ¿Alguien sabe por qué no me elimina el primer elemento de la lista?, se supone el apuntador se llama inicio, pero muevo inicio a la siguiente posición y borro el nodo, pero no se elimina. ¿Saben por qué?

Se define el Nodo

```
typedef struct Molde{ //Molde es el nombre de la estructura
    int dato;
    struct Molde *sig; //El puntero siguiente para recorrer la lista enlazada
}Nodo; //Nodo es el tipo de dato para declarar la estructura

typedef Nodo *tapuntador; //Apuntador al tipo de dato Nodo
tapuntador inicio=NULL;
```

Prototipos aquí...

En el main...

```
        case 4: printf("Dar el dato a eliminar: ");
                scanf(" %d", &x);
                borrarNodo(inicio, x);
                break;
```

Para insertar en la lista...

```
void insertarEnLista (tapuntador *inicio, int e){
    tapuntador nuevo; //Creamos un nuevo nodo
    nuevo = malloc(sizeof(Nodo)); //Utilizamos malloc para reservar memoria para ese nodo
    nuevo->dato = e; //Le asignamos el dato ingresado por pantalla a ese nodo
    nuevo->sig = *inicio; //Le asignamos al siguiente el dato de inicio
    *inicio = nuevo; //inicio pasa a ser el ultimo nodo agregado
}
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero... el problema comienza en borrarnodo. ¿Será por estar autoreferenciada?

```
tapuntador borrarNodo (tapuntador inicio, int valor){
   tapuntador aBorrar;

    if(inicio!=NULL){
        if(inicio->dato==valor){
            aBorrar=inicio;
            inicio=(inicio->sig);
            free(aBorrar);
        }else
            inicio->sig=borrarNodo(inicio->sig, valor);
    }
return inicio;
}
```

Comment: ¿`inicio` es una variable global o es local a la función `main`?

Comment: Es la cabeza de la lista, sólamente que le puse inicio, en el main se invoca la función y se le pasa la cabeza, o "inicio" y bueno, es de tipo apuntador a Nodo

Comment: No pregunté lo que es `inicio`, mi pregunta fué ¿`inicio` es una variable global o es local a la función `main`?